# Laravel and ajax call error 500

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have problem with ajax call.
I have select boxe.
If I choose the option on select box.
it will show the table data.

It said error 500.

controller code :

```
use App\Vendor;
public function getFormPaket()
    {
        $IDs=Vendor::select('id_vendor')->get();
        return view('paket2',compact('IDs'));
    }

public function getDataPaket(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax())
    {
        $vendor=Vendor::find($request->vendorid);
        $internets=$vendor->internets;
        return response($internets);
    }
}
```

paket2.blade.php ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            loadScore(1)
        })

        function loadScore(vendorid)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'get',
                url :"{{url('getDataScore')}}",
                data : {vendorid:vendorid},
                dataType : 'json',
                success:function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Can you fix this error?

Comment: first check the response of your ajax call .. what does it says ?

Comment: in the network tab .. click your ajax call and check the response ..

Comment: @rizkyZulkarnaen what exact error are you getting?

Comment: @Demonyowh : please check https://imgur.com/a/iiN5q .

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya please check  imgur.com/a/iiN5q

Comment: @rizkyZulkarnaen click on that red text it will give you the exact error message

Comment: 500 error is internal server error, which means, the problem is with the Laravel Application. Also, show us your route.

Comment: click on that red then check on network .. as per @NikhilRadadiya it will give you the exact error message ..

Comment: Thank's guys.. already done. Sorry because Im newbie in laravel